# Does Razor look in Solution Folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, namespaces

I'm trying to use a model from a custom namespace in my .cshtml file. However, whenever I try to set the model, Razor throws a `The type or namespace name could not be found` error.

I've got a project setup that uses solution folders to help with organization as shown below:
[image: Shows the FolderStructure of MyProject]

Here's what the code in the MyViewModel.cs file looks like:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Alright, so that is the basic layout. The problem is that when I try to use the `MyViewModel` object in my Razor view, Razor says that it can't find the namespace. As shown here:
[image: Razor cannot find the namespace]

I believe I'm doing everything the way I should. It just seems like Razor is failing to look in the solution folders. How can I get the `MyViewModel` object to be recognized by Razor? Is there something I am missing?

Please note: I do realize that I could simply change my `@using` statement to reference the entire path. However, in my project I have many solution folders inside the ViewModels folder and I do not wish to go through and specify each one.

**Update**

I've accepted Darin's answer because it successfully answers the question. I've also provided some more information below about my specific situation and why this question came up.

I looked into the issue a bit more and figured out what was going on. I normally use the SparkViewEngine which allows for referencing my view models like this: `<viewdata model="ViewModels.MyViewModel"/>` When Razor did not allow me to reference the view models in the same manner I thought there was something wrong with Razor.

Each ViewEngine creates temporary CS files which are used to help generate the view. The temporary files created by Spark use the "controllers" namespace. In this case Spark would have used the `MyProject.Controllers` namespace in it's temporary CS file. This means that I can reference the `ViewModels.MyViewModel` object without specifying the full namespace because it is in the same namespace as the generated CS file.

The temporary files that are generated by Razor use the `ASP` namespace. This means that I cannot reference the `ViewModels.MyViewModel` object without specifying the full namespace because it is not in the same namespace as the generated CS file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the namespace in which the your view model is declared to the top of your razor view using the `@using` directive:

```
@using MvcApplication1.ViewModels
@model MyViewModel
```

Also to avoid adding this in every single razor view you would like to use it, you could add it to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file (do not confuse with `~/web.config`):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="MvcApplication1.ViewModels" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Also notice how I have specified the full namespace. In the screenshot you have shown you seem to only be using `ViewModels.MyViewModel` but are you sure that this is the correct namespace? Usually when you add a class file in Visual Studio it will use the application name + folder to prefix the namespace like `MvcApplication1.ViewModels`.

Comment: thanks for your response. The correct namespace is `MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel`. I am using `ViewModels.MyViewModel` as you noticed, but just above that I declared a `@using MyProject`. I would think that Razor would know to look for `ViewModels` inside of `MyProject` due to my using statement.

Comment: No, your using statement should be `@using MyProject.ViewModels` and then you could use `MyViewModel` directly.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out what was going on. Normally I use the Spark view engine, and it allows me to specify the model with `ViewModels.MyViewModel`. It comes down to the actual namespace that Spark uses in it's temporary files and the namespace that Razor uses in it's temporary files. Spark uses the controller namespace i.e. `MyProject.Controllers` which knows about `ViewModels.MyViewModel`. Razor uses the ASP namespace `ASP` which does not know about `ViewModels.MyViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

The `@using` directive should point at your namespace:

```
@using MyProject.ViewModels
```

And then declare your model as the class:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

Or, use the full name directly:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel
```